# Autocomplete try catch (not standard Exception)

Tags: c#, exception, autocomplete

Is there any shortcut for invoke auto-complete try catch block.
But the main problem is I don't wan't to catch simple Exception but all Exceptions that can occur in selected piece of code.

For example:

```
    try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("test");
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            // code
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // code
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible, since there is nothing to tell you which exceptions a method can raise (except the documentation, which is not always accurate).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about two things, 
1. Throwing exception (autocomplete try catch block)
2. Use Exception class in catch block (for catching all exceptions).

Link below describs exception handling in C# in great details. And could answer your question in better way.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125470/Exception-Handling-for-C-Beginners